# Jboss Cartridges and management console access

Tags: jboss, openshift

I have installed Origin on my Virtualbox as VM

Now I have installed some of the cartridges on top it... like perl and Jboss

while I try to dwelve more into Jboss, I am like not sure how to access the management console on the Jboss EAP server, and do the admin tasks...

Please help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the management console by either sshing to your gear, or using rhc port-forward to enable connecting to the ports used by jbosseap on your gear directly from your local machine (this should work for origin or online)

```
corey-redhat:~ cdaley$ rhc port-forward jbosseap
Checking available ports ... done
Forwarding ports ...

To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address

Service Local               OpenShift
------- -------------- ---- ----------------
java    127.0.0.1:3528  =>  127.3.240.1:3528
java    127.0.0.1:4447  =>  127.3.240.1:4447
java    127.0.0.1:5445  =>  127.3.240.1:5445
java    127.0.0.1:5455  =>  127.3.240.1:5455
java    127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.3.240.1:8080
java    127.0.0.1:9990  =>  127.3.240.1:9990
java    127.0.0.1:9999  =>  127.3.240.1:9999

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

After doing the port forward, you can use `http://localhost:9990` (or whatever port is forwarded for you) to reach the admin web gui for jbosseap